# Am I correct in how these look in terms of threading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have these 2 simple methods for example

```
private static void InsertPerson(string firstName, string lastName)
{
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
     {
          connection.Open();
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
          (
               connection, 
               $'INSERT INTO [People] ([FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES ('{firstName}','{lastName}'
          );
     );
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }    
}

private static Task InsertPersonAsync(string firstName, string lastName)
{
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
     {
          await connection.OpenAsync();
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
          (
               connection, 
               $'INSERT INTO [People] ([FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES ('{firstName}','{lastName}'
          );
     );
         await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
     }    
}
```

I'm wondering how each of the following looks in terms of threads:

(1)

```
Task t1 = InsertPersonAsync("Crazy", "Bernie");
Task t2 = InsertPersonAsync("Crooked", "Hillary");
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

(2)

```
Task t1 = InsertPersonAsync("Crazy", "Bernie");
Task t2 = InsertPersonAsync("Crooked", "Hillary");
await t1;
await t2;
```

(3)

```
Task t1 = InsertPersonAsync("Crazy", "Bernie").ConfigureAwait(false);
Task t2 = InsertPersonAsync("Crooked", "Hillary").ConfigureAwait(false);
await t1;
await t2;
```

(4)

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => InsertPerson("Crazy", "Bernie"));
Task t2 = Task.Run(() => InsertPerson(("Crooked", "Hillary"));
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```

(5)

```
Action a1 = new Action(() => InsertPerson("Crazy", "Bernie"));
Action a2 = new Action(() => InsertPerson("Crooked", "Hillary"));
Action[] actions = new Action[] { a1, a2 };
Parallel.Invoke(actions);
```

This is what I think for (1)

```
    "Beneath" | ............................... first awaited stuff in t1 ....... and first awaited stuff in t2  ... (first awaited stuff in t1 just finished) ............ start next awaited stuff in t1 ......... (first awaited stuff in t2 just finished) ..........  start next awaited stuff in t2 ... 
    ==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
    Thread 1  | stuff before first await in t1 | stuff before first await in t2 | --------------------------------- | stuff after first await, before second await, in t1 | ---------------------------------------| stuff after first await, before second await, in t2 | ----------------------------------|
```

Is that correct, and can you help me visualize 2,3,4,5 as well?

Comment: Not related to your question, but please don't write SQL like that. Use *parameters*. using string formatting a) opens your code up to SQL injection and b) leads to everything being converted to/from strings, which *introduces* formatting issues in general.

Comment: Only 1 thread is used with both sync and async versions. Asynchronous IO calls, including async calls to SQL Server don't use threads. They use the OS's support for asynchronous IO to hand off the IO request to the OS and get notified when the IO operations completes. The calling thread isn't blocked. Some providers don't do that and fake async by using threads. One such case is MySQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I realize that, and that's why I made a "Beneath" line to describe what happens "under" threads at the time

Comment: @user7127000 all snippets that use the async method do *not* use any threads, whether they use `ConfigureAwait` or not. `ConfigureAwait` has to do with how execution continues after the async operation completes. Their execution isn't affected by the subsequent `await t1; await t2` or `await Task.WhenAll` calls. The async operations start when you call `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, not when you call `await`

Comment: You can check what happens, how many threads and how many tasks are used if you open the `Parallel Stacks` debug window while debugging